# Nice way to manage Docker image with several ENVs that differ by client and environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, cloud, devops

So me and the DevOps squad are in a battle against a growing problem: our front-end Docker image needs several build-time environment variables (meaning they need to be on the OS level instead of parameterized on the cloud), which are captured by ARG statements and assigned to ENVs either on the pipeline or building locally by passing `docker build -t project --build-arg ...` (which has security issues since all ENVs are stored in the layer's metadata and therefore visible with `docker history`). That was fine when we had a few args, but as the project keeps growing it just adds more and more dependence on the DevOps squad to always be updating the pipeline with the new ARGs and different values that differ not only by client (in prod) but also environment (we have the usual dev, stage, prod) so the development and stage environments won't break, not to mention prod. I can't provide much details but in short some variables are feature toggles, others contain cloud credentials, framework stuff, etc. I've already tried using `--mount=type=secret...` but it's not ideal since the front-end runtime needs them in context. Passing an `env_file` to the build command looks like the best idea, but how to keep the file secure and manageable by the front-end squads? Also, compose is not an option here, our pipeline does not use it to orchestrate containters and it would fall under the same file problem I think. We had the idea of somehow commiting the env file cryptographed and somehow always do this process via a git hook or something, and then have the contents accessed inside the pipeline with a private key. Doesn't sound too fancy imo. Anyways, help and ideas are greatly appreciated here!

Comment: With so few actual details this will be a little hard to answer.  You do highlight a couple of things like cloud credentials that absolutely positively should not be built into an image.  Is it possible to restructure things so you have a single image that all of your end users share, and then inject the credentials and other settings at the point where you run the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze sorry for not providing much details, depending on what would be helpful I can try to give more. We already have single images for each environment though, the hassle is contacting the devops guys everytime we add something, and other squads do it too. But you're saying we should provide the values at the docker run step instead? That may be worth looking into...

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the variables as secrets in something like HashiCorp Vault.

If you are using HashiCorp Vault, you can ARG the Vault's ip/port/token in the dockerfile and fetch the secret with the vault API in a variable in the dockerfile (RUN command) itself, works perfectly. If you want to set the variables as environmental variable, then store them in .bashrc or /etc/profile file after fetching from Vault.